# Python - win32api GetModuleHandle error "the specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x, pywin32

I'm using the the code below to get some information about running processes. However, I seem to be having trouble using the module names to preform the functions. For example, as soon as the below code gets to `win32api.GetModuleHandle(fileName)`, it crashes stating that `the specified module could not be found`. Any suggestions as to how I might fix this? Thank you much!

**Code:**

```
processName = "MyProcess"
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
hwnd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, processName).GetSafeHwnd()
pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)[1]
processHandle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
modules = win32process.EnumProcessModules(processHandle)
for module in modules:
    fileName = win32process.GetModuleFileName(processHandle, module)
    print('{:08X}'.format(module))
    print(fileName)
    print(win32api.GetModuleHandle(fileName))

processHandle.close()
```

**Edit:**

The first answer made me realize my "the specified module could not be found" is a bit ambiguous. This is a win32 module error, not a python module error. Everything is imported into python fine (I just left out the imports for brevity). The problem is with the line `print(win32api.GetModuleHandle(fileName))`. The more detailed error is `pywintypes.error: (126, 'GetModuleHandle', 'The specified module could not be found.')`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here that you can't do just by using the original `module` values?

Comment: @abamert: I was actually just playing around with these functions at the moment and was wondering what was wrong. I will eventually be wanting to get the base address of the process to use for ReadProcessMemory purposes, but that's not what I was specifically doing here.

Comment: If you're trying to build a cheat program or trainer maker, you may want to search for what already exists. There are multiple modules out there that, while they may be incomplete and/or out-of-date, have a lot of useful source that shows how to do most of the hard parts. (One of them is a project I abandoned almost a decade ago that wrapped up similar functionality in OS X, linux 2.x, and Win32, which I later found that someone else had forked and revived but then abandoned again… unfortunately, I can't remember the name of his fork.)

Comment: @abarnert: I am working on getting something to read game values, but specifically so that I can write an AI for the game. I suppose a python module that takes the work out of connecting with the process and reading all the necessary memory would be useful, but I need to take if from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking a handle from a *different* process, getting its filename, then asking for the same filename's handle in *your* process.

Unless you happen to have already opened the module in your process too, there *is* no such handle in your process. As the [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs explain, "The module must have been loaded by the calling process" (that is, by you).

If you wanted to open the module, use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you wanted the handle from the other process… well, you already *have* that. If you need to get a handle with different access rights or something, explain what it is you actually need to do, and it's probably doable.